# statistic test on univariate time series without replicates in R

Tags: r, statistics, time-series

I'm having the following data on an experiment, where I want to find out, how an bacterium reacts on two similar levels (nucleic acids) to a treatment. 
[image]
Treatment happened after the sampling on day 0 (vertical dashed line). As you can see, it got more abundant (line is average, dots are measured triplicates). I have 3 technical replicates (doing the lab work 3 times on the same sample) but no biological replicates.
For publication purposes, I want to show that the induced change is significant. So far I used a two tailed t test for heteroscedastic samples, using the 3 sample points day -25 to 0 as sample group 1 and 5 sample points day 3 to 17 as sample group 2 (this is the range where most of my bacteria reacted).
Afterwards I performed the Bonferroni correction on the p values to correct for multiple testing. But is this the correct way and is it possible with only technical replicates?

I'm finding many hints on fitting models to my graph, but I only want to test for statistic significance of difference between before and after treatment. So I'm searching for the correct statistics and also how to apply it in R. Any help appreciated!

here is the plot:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(scales)
ggplot(data=sample_data, aes(x=days-69,y=value,colour=nucleic_acid,group=nucleic_acid,lty=nucleic_acid))+ 
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept=0),linetype="dashed", size=1.2)+
    geom_point(aes(),colour="black")+
    stat_summary(aes(colour=nucleic_acid),colour="black",fun.y="mean", geom="line", size=1.5)+
    scale_linetype_manual(values=c("dna"=1,"cdna"=4),
                        name="Nucleic acid  ",
                        breaks=c("cdna","dna"),
                        labels=c("16S rRNA","16S rDNA"))+
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 20))+
    theme_bw()+
    scale_y_continuous(label= function(x) {ifelse(x==0, "0", parse(text=gsub("[+]", "", gsub("e", " %*% 10^", scientific_format()(x)))))})+
    theme(axis.title.y = element_text(angle=90,vjust=0.5))+
    theme(axis.text=element_text(size=12))+
    theme(legend.text=element_text(size=11))+
    theme(panel.grid.major=element_line(colour = NA, size = 0.2))+
    theme(panel.grid.minor=element_line(colour = NA, size = 0.5))+
    theme(legend.position="bottom")+
    theme(legend.background = element_rect(fill="grey90",linetype="solid"))+
    labs(x="Days",
             y=expression(atop("Absolute abundance in cell equivalents",bgroup("[",relative~abundance~x~cells~mL^{-1},"]"))))
```

and here is my data:

```
sample_data<-structure(list(time = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L), days = c(83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 
86L, 86L, 86L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 
98L, 98L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 
112L, 112L, 112L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 126L, 126L, 
126L, 126L, 133L, 133L, 133L, 133L, 133L, 133L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 
140L, 140L, 140L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 62L, 62L, 62L, 
62L, 62L, 62L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 
72L, 72L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 79L, 79L, 79L, 79L, 79L, 
79L), parallel = c(3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 2L), nucleic_acid = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("cdna", "dna"), class = "factor"), 
    habitat = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "water", class = "factor"), 
    value = c(5316639.62, 6402573.912, 6294710.95, 2369809.996, 
    2679661.691, 2105693.166, 2108794.224, 2487177.041, 6021765.438, 
    5524939.499, 6016021.786, 2628427.206, 3164229.113, 896068.7656, 
    2966515.364, 4436008.425, 1860580.149, 3911309.508, 888489.0268, 
    1004334.365, 1141636.992, 961140.0729, 1072009.18, 1134997.852, 
    668013.4333, 459645.1058, 645944.1129, 702293.6865, 590620.3693, 
    642136.7523, 932531.1588, 1224299.065, 1502344.5, 1545034.46, 
    1122002.798, 1411050.57, 1465061.711, 1378876.488, 810348.2823, 
    1361496.248, 1056558.288, 897876.4169, 931519.9524, 1165768.09, 
    957873.9045, 746011.7558, 624116.5603, 522209.2283, 551120.1371, 
    440096.4446, 565108.4447, 373304.8604, 266595.7171, 333767.4042, 
    185612.6681, 144899.8736, 173739.3969, 211490.827, 223815.0867, 
    296455.4243, 1278759.217, 247292.4355, 1171554.199, 1146278.577, 
    227443.8462, 233542.6719, 253224.2629, 875040.4892, 1151921.616, 
    1285744.479, 355381.9156, 110724.7928, 252238.9632, 912865.3372, 
    608269.6498, 500307.5301, 774955.9598, 1374106.94, 3121909.308, 
    1071086.757, 3033665.589, 2984567.998, 1396313.444, 1356465.773, 
    4480581.956, 4273141.231, 4957691.655, 1910056.657, 5520085.32, 
    5094686.657, 5990052.759, 2272441.566, 1513268.608, 1821716.75
    ), treatment2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Treatment", class = "factor")), .Names = c("time", 
"days", "parallel", "nucleic_acid", "habitat", "value", "treatment2"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(51243L, 51244L, 51245L, 
51246L, 51247L, 51248L, 51255L, 51256L, 51257L, 51258L, 51259L, 
51260L, 51267L, 51268L, 51269L, 51270L, 51271L, 51272L, 51279L, 
51280L, 51281L, 51282L, 51283L, 51284L, 51291L, 51292L, 51293L, 
51294L, 51295L, 51296L, 51303L, 51304L, 51305L, 51306L, 51307L, 
51308L, 51315L, 51316L, 51317L, 51318L, 51319L, 51320L, 51326L, 
51327L, 51328L, 51329L, 51336L, 51337L, 51338L, 51339L, 51340L, 
51341L, 51348L, 51349L, 51350L, 51351L, 51352L, 51353L, 51360L, 
51361L, 51362L, 51363L, 51364L, 51365L, 51372L, 51373L, 51374L, 
51375L, 51376L, 51377L, 51384L, 51385L, 51386L, 51387L, 51388L, 
51389L, 51396L, 51397L, 51398L, 51399L, 51400L, 51401L, 51408L, 
51409L, 51410L, 51411L, 51412L, 51413L, 51420L, 51421L, 51422L, 
51423L, 51424L, 51425L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to test for significance of the effect of your treatment and you know how to fit model(s) on your data, you can simply fit a model which includes your treatment effect and a model which doesn't. Then compare the models by means of a likelihood ratio test.

In R it is pretty straightforward (I assume for simplicity a linear model, which anyway may not be the best choice, based on your data):

```
 # Models fit
 model_effect <- lm(y~Time + Treatment, data)
 model_null   <- lm(y~Time, data)

 # Models comparison
 anova(model_effect, model_null)
```

Comment: Hey Antonio, thanks for your response. I would assume that a glm might be more suitable for the shape of my data? But a general question: why is a model necessary for the statistics? Why can't I use the values that I have already?

Comment: This is more a statistical question rather than a programming question so you will find better help on [CorssValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). Anyway the quick answer is that when you do a t-test you are making a test on the parameters of a model. So every time you perform a statistical analysis (t-test, ANOVA, ANCOVA) you are implicitly fitting a regression model to your data. My suggestion is to directly compare two different models (with and without the treatment) and see which one best fits to your data. Based on this you can conclude that your treatment has an effect or not.

Comment: okay, I will try some models and see which fits best. thanks for the statistics clarification, though, it is not my brightest field ;-) good to know R makes it so easy